EAS build failed after install expo-updates, the error Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseUpdatesResources'
Error: @build-script-error-begin
Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. SHA-1 for file /home/expo/workingdir/build/global.css.android.js is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
@build-script-error-end
at createManifestForBuildAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/utils/build/createManifestForBuildAsync.js:44:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/utils/build/createUpdatesResources.js:26:5


Task :app:createReleaseUpdatesResources FAILED
Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUploadCleanUp SKIPPED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseUpdatesResources'.


Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 11m 6s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
1583 actionable tasks: 1583 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
